# How to jump from the first record to the last record in my database

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I have this piece of Java code in which I try to loop through the records, means I want to jump from the first records to the last and and vice versa. As you can see 'n' iterates forward through the records and 'p' iterates backwards. As soon as I reach the last record/first record an exception is thrown. How do I solve this?

Thanks in advace for your help :-)

```
public void NavigateTable() {
    try {
        statement = dbconnect.connect.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
        rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM author");
        char selection;
        rs.beforeFirst();
        do {
            System.out.println("(n)ext data, (p)revious data or (e)xit.");
            selection = readChar("");
            if (selection == 'n') {
                rs.next();
                System.out.print("AuthorID: " + rs.getInt("authorid"));
                System.out.print("\tFirst name: " + rs.getString("firstname"));
                System.out.print("\tLast name: " + rs.getString("lastname"));
                System.out.print("\tPublisherID: " +rs.getInt("publisherid")); 
                System.out.println();      
            } else if (selection == 'p') {
                rs.previous();
                System.out.print("AuthorID: " + rs.getInt("authorid"));
                System.out.print("\tFirst name: " + rs.getString("firstname"));
                System.out.print("\tLast name: " + rs.getString("lastname"));
                System.out.print("\tPublisherID: " +rs.getInt("publisherid")); 
                System.out.println();   
            }

        } while (selection != 'e'); 
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception " + e.getMessage());
    }

}
```

Comment: Exception ResultSet not positioned properly, perhaps you need to call next.

Comment: @Marta: It is obvious, in case if you are standing `beforeFirst` and trying to find a `previous`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are blindly scrolling off the ends of the `ResultSet`.  You need to use the `isFirst()` and `isLast()` methods to check if you are at the start or end, and then avoid calling `next()` or `previous()` in those cases.

Comment: Use while((rs.next)) to test if there another records else get the last record

Comment: @ElhadiMamoun That's fine if you are processing all rows in a loop, but in this case he's trying to let the user dictate processing direction.  A while loop makes no sense here.

Answer (score 1):

You should read all the records immediately and put them in something like an `ArrayList`, where you can easily jump from first to last and vice versa. This also lets you release the database resources, which is a Good Thing.

Comment: What if the resultset is 1 billion rows?

Comment: @JimGarrison: Let us hope, OP is not selecting `*` with no `where`. :)

Comment: @JimGarrison: Then you need more sophisticated methods, but this approach will work in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you don't want to have `ResultSet`s open while a user is interacting with the system (i.e. reading input from the user to determine whether to go forward or backward).

That being said, to solve you problem, you could try something like this:

```
public void NavigateTable() {
    try {
        statement = dbconnect.connect.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
        rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM author");
        char selection;
        rs.beforeFirst();
        do {
            System.out.println("(n)ext data, (p)revious data or (e)xit.");
            selection = readChar("");
            if (selection == 'n') {
                if (rs.isLast()) rs.beforeFirst();
                else rs.next();
                System.out.print("AuthorID: " + rs.getInt("authorid"));
                System.out.print("\tFirst name: " + rs.getString("firstname"));
                System.out.print("\tLast name: " + rs.getString("lastname"));
                System.out.print("\tPublisherID: " +rs.getInt("publisherid")); 
                System.out.println();      
            } else if (selection == 'p') {
                if (rs.isFirst()) rs.afterLast();
                else rs.previous();
                System.out.print("AuthorID: " + rs.getInt("authorid"));
                System.out.print("\tFirst name: " + rs.getString("firstname"));
                System.out.print("\tLast name: " + rs.getString("lastname"));
                System.out.print("\tPublisherID: " +rs.getInt("publisherid")); 
                System.out.println();

            }
```